# Catch GET request parameters in a Map<String,String>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to catch key value pairs in a Map parameter at spring MVC side.  This looks to me to be something simple but I can't wrap my head around it at the moment.  Take following url

```
www.goudengids.be.localhost:8080/ms/view/sendContactForm.ajah?pageId=711408&listingId=685592&siteId=353009&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.goudengids.be.localhost%3A8080%2Fms%2Fms%2Fkbc-bank-versicherung-recht-4780%2Fms-353009-preview%2F&moduleId=65920100&mySiteId=353009&pageShortId=1&prefills[Naam]=janneke
```

You'll notice at the end my latest attempt to get this working prefills[Naam]=janneke.  I like to catch this in the following controller.

```
public String getContactForm(@RequestParam(required = true) Long moduleId, @RequestParam(required = true) String url, @RequestParam(required=false) Map<String,String> prefills, Long mySiteId, Integer pageShortId,
      DefaultPageParameters defaultPageParameters, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) throws Exception {
```

However I'm recieving all parameters in the request in my prefills variable instead of just Naam,janneke.  Is this even possible what I'm attempting or should I go with a large string with a token to tokenize ?

```
prefills=naam:janneke|title:maan|subject:space
```

Comment: I think the typical approach would be to use a different, optional `@RequestParam` for each "prefill" value.

Comment: That would work if we had fixed values, but in this case we are talking about situations where you don't know how many prefill fields you can have.  One form can have only two fields another can have thousands (well sort of there are a few limits).  But I can't hardcode x variables in the controller

Comment: I don't see `title` or `subject` params in your example request. Where are they coming from?

Comment: ah well they where from another example it seems.  The point of the story is that the fields can be anything.  This functionality handles about custom forms users can create for their website.  They can call it anything, but sometimes you want fields prefilled if they open the form, for example sharing a picture, then they click on the picture, the form opens with a picture field prefilled with the picture url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a clean way out, so I went for the pragmatic solution

```
  public String getContactForm(@RequestParam(required = true) Long moduleId, @RequestParam(required = true) String url, @RequestParam(required=false) List<String> prefills, Long mySiteId, Integer pageShortId,
      DefaultPageParameters defaultPageParameters, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) throws Exception {


  private void prefillFieldsWithData(List<String> prefills, ModelMap model, BasicContactFormVo contactFormVo) {
    if(prefills != null && !prefills.isEmpty()){
      Map<String, String> valuesOfCustomFields = new HashMap<String, String>();
      List<ContactFormElementVo> customFormElements = contactFormVo.getCustomFormElements();
      for (String prefillData : prefills) {
        if(prefillData.contains("|")){
          String[] prefillFieldData = prefillData.split("|");
          for (ContactFormElementVo contactFormElementVo : customFormElements) {
            if(contactFormElementVo.getLabel().equals(prefillFieldData[0])){
              valuesOfCustomFields.put("cfe"+contactFormElementVo.getId().toString(), prefillFieldData[1]);
              break;
            }
          }                    
        }
      }
      model.addAttribute("customFieldValues",valuesOfCustomFields);
    }
  }
```

It's a bit sad I have to do it this way, but it seems Spring has a generic way of detecting a Map as request parameter and filling it with all parameters in the request.  There is no way around that except overloading that class which I rather do not considering it's part of the entire MVC mechanic.

I call the controller now with following URL.  It works just ... meh ... not my favorite solution

```
http://www.goudengids.be.localhost:8080/ms/view/sendContactForm.ajah?pageId=711408&listingId=685592&siteId=353009&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.goudengids.be.localhost%3A8080%2Fms%2Fms%2Fkbc-bank-versicherung-recht-4780%2Fms-353009-preview%2F&moduleId=65920100&mySiteId=353009&pageShortId=1&prefills=Naam|janneke%20zag%20eens%20pruimen&prefills=E-mail|maan
```